# Thumbnail from liveleak

Tags: php, liveleak

Is there any way how I can get thumbnail from liveleak videos using PHP?

It's easy to get thumbnail from youtube, vimeo, dailymotion, metacafe but I didn't find any information about liveleak.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you can scrape the video page then you can look for og:image tag in meta tags.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="..."/>
```

Content property will have url for thumbnail.

For example, for:
http://www.liveleak.com/view?i=a5c_1485250453
meta tag will be:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://cdn.liveleak.com/80281E/ll_a_u/thumbs/2017/Jan/24/b124049d23c2_sf_3.jpg"/>
```